# Blender on Mac 10.6 text not showing up

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So the text on Blender on 10.6 isn't showing up, pretty much at all. 
I'm setting up Blender for a friend and I don't use Mac so I have no idea how to fix it and I couldn't find any fix while Googling.

Comment: Do you mean the text of UI? Or a text object in your scene?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering the same. Do your mean the user interface text strings or a text object in the 3D scene? Are you using an integrated Intel graphics card? In either case that sounds like a bug and should probably reported to the bug tracker instead.

Comment: Sorry, things got a bit busy. 
I mean everything, some text is shown. But only parts of it.
It's an old Mac so I'm sure it's the integrated Intel graphics, but I'll double check when I get a chance. 

I'll report it as a bug just in case it actually is a bug.